# Reproving a standard result about singular homology with methods from model categories

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

If $A \rightarrow X$ is a cofibration of topological spaces then the induced map $H_i(X,A)\rightarrow H_i(X/A,*)$ is an isomorphism. I am aware of many proofs of this fact but none use methods from category theory? I think this should be possible because the result also holds for the case of simplicial sets, if $B \rightarrow Y$ is a cofibration of simplicial sets (equivalently, a monomorphism), then $H_i(Y,B) \rightarrow H_i(Y/B,*)$ is an isomorphism

My question is then if we can prove this fact about singular homology using the assumptions that Serre fibrations, weak equivalences and cofibrations make $\textbf{Top}$ into a model category and using the fact that for the Reedy model structure on $\textbf{Top}^ \Delta$, the cosimplicial object $U:\Delta \rightarrow \textbf{Top}:[n] \mapsto \Delta^n$ is cofibrant and some additional assumptions?

Comment: It is not really a fact about singular homology. It is true for each (generalized) homology theory satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (except possibly the dimension axiom). The essence is that if $A$ is *contractible* and $A \to X$ is a cofibration, then the quotient map $p : X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: If you know that the homology theory satisfies the *weak homotopy equivalence axiom* (which means that weak homotopy equivalences  are mapped to isomorphisms by the homology functors), then it would be sufficient to know that the above $p$ is a weak equivalence. Singular homology satisfies this axiom. However I do not see how to give a proof concerning $p$ based only on a model structure.